# Overriding salesforce1 standard page result in loop

Tags: salesforce1-app

I actually override my account edit button with a visualforce page, that will redirect to the standard page using the override=1 to certain user , while other users will be redirect to another page for a request. On the web it works well. When adapting it to mobile, the override=1 doesn't not work. It redirect constantly on my vf, thus resulting in an infine loop.

It seems that they already fix the bug, as mention in this post : [Override Standard New button in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/override-standard-new-button-in-salesforce1). But, it doesn't work for my case. I tried doing it in apex, also using js, but none of the below methods work:

sforce.one.navigateToSObject(accid,"edit"),

sforce.one.navigateToURL('/' + accid + '/e?nooverride=1&retURL=%2F' + accid),

sforce.one.editRecord(accid)

They all enter an infine loop. Does someone encounter this problem, with a solution to it ?

Comment: Seems to be exact same issue I'm having myself here. Have you found any solution for this yet?

Comment: unfortunately, even salesforce developper team has not responded. We logged a case on the issue, but we had only basic support from salesforce, which doesn't cover development issues.They guided me to the salesforce forum, but no answer on their part too.

Comment: @vanessen did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I recently came across the resolution from salesforce, stating that you can now override in salesforce1. But i don't remember which of the above functions now works, but it is available in the current release.

Comment: @vanessen - Did you ever find a working example/alternative for nooverride in the SF1 context? I'm struggling with this.... Thanks!