# How can I read ParentId value in SF1 app when override Standard new button on Contact?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce1-app, aura

I have overriden std. new button on Contact record to pre-populate some values during Contact record creation. For this I have used aura component to override std. new button and then I call LWC from Aura to navigate to Contact record create page using navigation mixin.

**Below is the code:**

cmp:

```
    <aura:component
        implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasSObjectName,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable"
        access="global">
        <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="Id" />
        <aura:attribute name="selectedRecordId" type="Id" />
        <aura:attribute name="parentRecordId" type="Id" />
        <aura:attribute name="isShow" type="boolean" default="false" />
        <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
        <!--Declare Handler-->
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
        <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.reInit}" />
        <c:newAccRecordWithDefaults recordTypeId="{!v.selectedRecordId}" objectName="{!v.sObjectName}" parentRecordId="{!v.parentRecordId}"/>

</aura:component>
```

controller JS:

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        var device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        var accountId = component.get("v.recordId");
        let objectName = component.get("v.sObjectName");

 
        // I can read Parent Record Id value in Desktop but its not working in SF1 app.
        var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
        console.log('###RecordTypeId : '+pageReference.state.recordTypeId);
        component.set("v.selectedRecordId", pageReference.state.recordTypeId);
        var getAccId = pageReference.state.additionalParams;
        if(typeof getAccId !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('###GetAccID : '+getAccId);
            getAccId = getAccId.replace('accid=','');
            getAccId = getAccId.substring(0,15);
            console.log('###AccId : '+getAccId);
            component.set("v.parentRecordId", getAccId);
        }

    },
    reInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('reinit method:');
        var device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        if (device !== 'PHONE') {
            $A.get('e.force:closeQuickAction').fire();
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
    }
})
```

Rerender js:

```
({
    rerender: function (component, helper) {
        let device = $A.get("$Browser.formFactor");
        if (device === 'DESKTOP') {
        this.superRerender();
        let recordTypeId = component.get("v.pageReference").state.recordTypeId;
        component.set("v.selectedRecordId", recordTypeId);
        }
        else{
            $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
        }
    }
})
```

LWC JS:

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    wire,
    api
} from 'lwc';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import {
    getRecord
} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {
    getObjectInfo
} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import COUNTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Account_Country__c';
import {
    encodeDefaultFieldValues
} from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils';
import {
    NavigationMixin
} from 'lightning/navigation';
import FORM_FACTOR from '@salesforce/client/formFactor';
const FIELDS = [COUNTRY_FIELD];
export default class NewAccRecordWithDefaults extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api parentRecordId;
    @api previousUrl;
    DefaultCountry;
    error;
    @api recordTypeId;
    @api objectName;
    isMobileCallonce = false;

    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: USER_ID,
        fields: FIELDS,
    })
    userDetails({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.DefaultCountry = data.fields.Account_Country__c.value;
            if (this.recordTypeId !== undefined) {
                this.navigateToNewRecWithDefaults();
            }

        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }


    navigateToNewRecWithDefaults() {
        const ContactDefaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            OtherCountryCode: this.DefaultCountry
        });
        const ContactParentDefaultValues = encodeDefaultFieldValues({
            OtherCountryCode: this.DefaultCountry,
            AccountId: this.parentRecordId
        });
        const ContactDefaultValuesMobile = {
            OtherCountryCode: this.DefaultCountry
        };
        const ContactParentDefaultValuesMobile = {
            OtherCountryCode: this.DefaultCountry
            AccountId: this.parentRecordId
        };
        if (FORM_FACTOR === 'Large') {
           if (this.objectName === 'Contact') {
                    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                        type: 'standard__objectPage',
                        attributes: {
                            objectApiName: this.objectName,
                            actionName: 'new'
                        },
                        state: {
                            count: '1',
                            nooverride: '1',
                            useRecordTypeCheck: '1',
                            defaultFieldValues: this.parentRecordId === undefined ? ContactDefaultValues : ContactParentDefaultValues,
                            navigationLocation: 'LIST_VIEW'
                            backgroundContext: this.parentRecordId === undefined ? '/lightning/o/Contact/list?filterName=Recent':'/lightning/o/Account/list?filterName=Recent',
                            recordTypeId: this.recordTypeId
                        }
                    });
            }
        } 
        //For Mobile...
        else {
            if (this.objectName === 'Contact') {
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__objectPage',
                    attributes: {
                        objectApiName: this.objectName,
                        actionName: 'new'
                    },
                    state: {
                        count: '1',
                        nooverride: '1',
                        defaultFieldValues: this.parentRecordId === undefined ? ContactDefaultValuesMobile : ContactParentDefaultValuesMobile, // set defaults as a nav parameter 
                        recordTypeId: this.recordTypeId,
                        backgroundContext: this.parentRecordId === undefined ? '/lightning/o/Contact/list?filterName=Recent':`/lightning/r/Account/${this.parentRecordId}/view`,//this does not work correctly in Mobile
                        navigationLocation: this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                            type: 'standard__objectPage',
                            attributes: {
                                objectApiName: this.objectName,
                                actionName: 'home'
                            }
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The above code works fine in Dekstop application **but when I goto SF1 and navigate to Account record, click on Related list and try to create Contact then it does not fetch Parent AccountId information.** Also, need some suggestion about navigation part as when I create Contact record from parent, it navigates to Contact record detail page instead of Account detail(as per standard behavior).

Can someone please suggest how can I capture parent details in SF1 app?

**Note :** I do not want to use Custom page here when I navigate to record create page.

Comment: Try to Override the Mobile Override option as well in the action.
Make sure your lightning component implements force:apphostable

Comment: I have already override std. new button for mobile app.

Comment: implements = force:apphostable - tried this ?

Comment: @NedlaV It is not working...

Comment: Might be an issue with page reference - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/override-standard-new-button-in-salesforce1?rq=1

Comment: Given link is not relevant to this query.

Answer (score 0):

It seems SF1 URL is not exposed to us directly and there is no direct way to fetch parentid. Similar idea is posted [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdpf9UAB/access-to-parent-lookups-in-lightning-components-invoked-from-related-lists).

One of the possible workaround I tried is when you navigate to Account detail page, create a hidden LWC that will store Account Id in session storage.
e.g.  `sessionStorage.setItem('AccountId', this.recordId);`

When you navigate to Contact creation page from Account related list, fetch this session storage value and set `parentRecordId` accordingly. Reset the session storage immediately after that. This logic can be written only for **mobile** application.

The only consideration here is when you login to SF1 app and navigate to Account record and then goto Contact tab and create a Contact from Contact tab, it pre-populate Account value which is incorrect but this could be a rare scenario in SF1 app.